# How do i make a single task inside forEach loop thread safe while using parallel method?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).parallel().forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(x);
    // Thread safe task
    someThreadSafeTask();
});
```

Consider having the list of Id which I append to some URl and make http call later I need to save the information to file which should be thread safe ? How to handle this ?

Comment: Don't use a parallel stream.

Comment: What if I want speed of parallel processing?

Comment: With the code you've shown you are probably multiple times slower than just using normal streams of even a for-loop

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have multiple threads writing to the *same* file, the answer is simply to open the file, write all that you have to do, and then close it synchronously. Even if you somehow manage to have the threads run in the order you want them to, you would still have the following problems:

1. The other threads would still need to wait their turn to run.
2. You would be opening the file, writing to it, and closing it, each time. This is incredibly time consuming.

If you need to write to multiple files, then you could implement a *per file* queue and have consumers writing to the respective files (but still, at most you will have N threads, where N is the number of **different** files to which you want to write).

Comment: Consider this, I have list of userid's which I append to some URL and make an http call , and I store the response to a file.  without using the parallel method the process slows down, so how should I address such problem.

Comment: @shreerangakv: Will each HTTP request be need to be stored to a different file?

Comment: no, just logging the particular fileds to single file